# I'm trying to make a bluetooth song transferring to other paired devices, but it won't work

Tags: windows, batch-file

My code rn is:

```
:transfer
set synced=%cuser%\synced_%devname%.txt
if not exist %synced% (echo.>>"%synced%")
if not exist %devid% (
    set goto=transfer
    goto device_id
)
cls
echo.
echo                             -Transfering-
echo.
echo.
::for /f %%b in ('dir %users% ^| find "File(s)"') do (set dmva=%%b)
::set /a rmt=%dmva%+%dmva%
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F "usebackq tokens=*" %%A in (!curdir!) do (
    findstr /m "%%A" %synced% >nul
    if %errorlevel%==1 (
        echo  ^>------------------------------------------------------------^<
        set /a dwl+=1
        echo  Currently Transferring: %%A
        echo  Total #!ttl!; Song #!dwl!; Success #!scs!; Failed #!err!
        echo  Estimated remaining time: !ttl_time!
        set v1=!time!
        btobex -n"%devname%" %%A
        set v2=!time!
        set /a remaining_songs=!ttl!-!dwl!
        set /a ft=!v2!-!v1!
        set /a ttl_time1=!ft! * !remaining_songs!
        set /a ttl_time2=!ttl_time1! / 60
        set ttl_time=!ttl_time2! minutes
        if !errorlevel!==1 (
            set /a err+=1
        ) else (
            set /a scs+=1
            echo %%A>>%synced%
        )
    )
)
endlocal
pause >nul
goto bsync
```

but instead of checking if every song name is not in a list, and sending the file, it outputs: `The system cannot find the file E:\Downloads\.`

I'm trying to debug this since 4 days rn, but I don't seem getting there.

Variable meanings:

- %cuser% is the variable I've set for a system of logged users. It defines the currently logged user.
- %devid% saves the target device's name.
- the rest is pretty explanatory ig...

Comment: `E:\Downloads\.` is clearly a directory, not a file, hence `findstr` will be unable to find a string within it with that syntax. `if %errorlevel%==1` will use the `errorlevel` as it was when the `for...%%A...` was parsed, not as the `findstr` set it; you need `if !errorlevel!==1` as you are using elsewhere in the code block. No idea what `btobex` is.

Comment: Change `if %errorlevel%==1 (` to ```if errorlevel 1 (```, and you may as well change `if !errorlevel!==1 (` to ```if errorlevel 1 (``` too.

Comment: do you have a folder called `Downloads` in a drive called `E`? - is this an external drive? is it mounted on the OS/System?